# How to assign an inferred type to a generic?

Tags: typescript, generics, angular-forms

How to assign an inferred type to a generic, without to have to define this type explicitly ?

For example, using strictly typed forms in Angular 14 :

```js
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

// Generic part

abstract class A<T> {
  form!: T;
}

// Extending part

type MyType = FormGroup<{ id: FormControl<number | null> }>; // Type I would like not to have to define

class A1 extends A<MyType> {
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    super();
  }

  setForm(): void {
    this.form = this.fb.group({ id: 2 }); // Inferred expression I want to use to specify generic T type of A
    this.form.value.code; // Error as expected : Property 'code' does not exist on type 'Partial<{ id: number | null; }>'
  }
}
```

Comment: Please either tag this with `angular-forms` or remove your example's dependency on it.